# Using s3 upload function using an imageURI?

Tags: image, cordova, ionic-framework, amazon-s3

I was wondering if it was possible to upload to S3 using the SDK with an imageURI.

I would like to upload a picture to my S3 bucket from a mobile phone camera or gallery. However, the cordova library only returns an imageURI for this picture. It seems like it doesn't work in the S3 upload function. I would prefer to avoid the complexities of the REST API and just use the SDK. Is this possible if I do not have a file object but only an image URI? I am using the Ionic framework if this is useful information to anybody.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: that is incorrect, the camera can return a file or you can convert the imageURI to a file

Comment: Do you mean the FILE_URI parameter?  I was never able to get that one to work.  How would I convert a imageURI into a file object?  https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#module_Camera.DestinationType

Comment: https://github.com/aaronksaunders/firebaseStorage2/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.ts#L63

Comment: That was very useful, thank you.